# how to switch to a variable sheet based on a cell value in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to create a button in google sheets and assign it a script which will take the user to a specific sheet based on a specific string in a cell.

I have played around trying to merge other answers to similar questions but i haven't been successful!

This is where i am at currently:

```
function sheetchanger() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var cell = ss.getRange("Lookup!B5");
ss.setActiveSheet(cell)
```

I am really, REALLY new to code, so please excuse the above if it is way off!

Thanks for any and all help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function sheetChanger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var first = ss.getSheetByName("Lookup");
  var range = first.getRange("B5:B5");
 range.activate();
}
```

Looking again, I think I misunderstood what you are trying to do. If you want to jump to Lookup!B5 then the above will work.

If you need to jump to the sheet that is named in Lookup!B5, then this will work:

```js
function sheetChanger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var first = ss.getSheetByName("Lookup");
  var range = first.getRange("B5");
  var cell = range.getCell(1,1);
  var sheet = cell.getValue();
  Logger.log(cell.getValue());
  ss.getSheetByName(sheet).getRange("A1").activate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob, that isn't what i was after, sorry for my poor explanation. I have managed to do it now!  I was trying to make a button that would go to a specific sheet based on the value in B5. e.g. if B5 was sheet2, the button would take me to sheet2 etc.

Comment: That's correct, if you insert a shape, you can assign the second script to that shape, and it becomes a button that will take you there.

Comment: You can also specify the active cell on the new sheet. I have it set to A1 but you can change that to any cell reference, and that will become the active cell when it takes you to the new sheet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in my terrible knowledge of coding, I asked the script to look at the data in B5 but not to take it....

```
function sheetchanger() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Lookup');
var cell = sheet.getRange("B5").getValue();

ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(cell));
}
```

I just needed to add the .getValue on it!